# Alt tag equivalent for external media-wiki images

Tags: mediawiki

Is there an alt tag equivalent for external media-wiki images, I know images from the internal gallery do.

The external image syntax `[image_url]` for internal you can do `[[image|alt="text"]]`

Answer (score 0):

There isn't. In general there is no way to set attributes on external images. You can enable [$wgAllowImageTag](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgAllowImageTag) and use `<img>` tags in wikicode or find some extension which embeds external images.